# call magento controller admin function from outside

Tags: magento

I want to access function of controller of Adminhtml from outside. I have tried using:

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
if(!class_exists('IWD_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderrController')) 
        {
            require_once('IWD_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderrController.php');        
        }
        $controller         = new IWD_OrderManager_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderrController(
                                    Mage::app()->getRequest(),
                                    Mage::app()->getResponse()
                                ); 
        $request            = $controller->getRequest();
        $response           = $controller->getResponse();
        $controller->blockdatesAction();
```

but it is not working.

It works using :

```
file_get_contents('http://url.com/[...]/controller/action/');
```

but it gives error:

```
{"ajaxExpired":1,"ajaxRedirect":"http:\/\/www.url.com\/index.php\/admin\/admin\/index\/login\/key\/b91e3bd674dd138b7ea5856117d59e20\/"}
```

I think it is because Adminhtml functions are not allowed access without login.

Is this something that I can achieve (even by making changes in core files for this case)?

Thanks in Advance.